# how to update label of other viewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, pass-data

I'm trying to set UIbutton's text in firstVC as selectedCity variable when it selected in tableViewCell in SecondVC . I cannot use segue or tabBarController.   [Updated photo of ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxNk0.png)

FirstVC

```
import UIKit

class homeView: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var selectRegion: UIButton!
}
```

SecondVC

```
import UIKit

class selectCityPage: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var selectedCity: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            selectedCity = "Almaty"
            
            
            
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1{
            selectedCity = "Усть-Каменогорск"
            
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       // when this view controller is dismissed, uibutton's text in next viewcontroller should equal to selectedCity
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Delegation you can achieve that

Comment: You can achieve that using NotificationCenter,Please Refer this https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/#back-closure tutorial for Pass Data between ViewControllers

Comment: I answered your question but can you please show how you present the SecondVC
from FirstVC? I need an instance of SecondVC  to set the delegate.

Comment: i have one navigation controller between first and second vc.

Comment: To present second vc i should tap uibutton than tap other button in other nav controller than it will present second vc

Comment: @Mat i answered your question

Comment: have you already wrote the code to present the secondVC? can you edit your answer?

Comment: Yes i used segue to transfer some data. used performSegue to move to vc

Comment: @Mat i watched a video on youtube  about protocols and i'm guessing what are u asking for. The  problem is user cannot move from firstVC straight to secondVC. there is one More VC with navigationController between them. to see secondVC, user should tap button in firstVC than tap one more button in VC between them, after than he will select city name. and that city will be shown as title of button in firstVC

Comment: i updated link to the photo of ui

Comment: I will update my code tomorrow. Let's see if it works

Comment: @МухаммедАралбек check new answer update. if you tell me the VCs name, I can update the answer but it should be quite easy for you to adapt my answer to you case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegation. These are the required steps:

1. Create a delegate protocol that defines the messages sent to the delegate.
2. Create a delegate property in the delegating class to keep track of the delegate.
3. Adopt and implement the delegate protocol in the delegate class.
4. Call the delegate from the delegating object.

SecondVC

```
import UIKit

//1. Create a delegate protocol
protocol CitySelectionDelegate {
  func pickCity(with selectedCity:String)
}

class SelectCityPage: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var selectedCity: String!

    //2. Create a delegate property in the delegating class
    var delegate:CitySelectionDelegate?


    //other stuff 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    if indexPath.row == 0{
       selectedCity = "Almaty"
    }
    if indexPath.row == 1{
       selectedCity = "Усть-Каменогорск"
    }

    4. Call the delegate from the delegating object.
    delegate?.pickCity(with: selectedCity) //call your delegate method 
    
    //dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)    when you dismiss is up to you    
    }
}
```

HomeViewController
UPDATE: Since you have another VC embedded inside a UINavigationController, both the Home and Select Region Page MUST conform to the delegate and you have to set the delegate inside prepareForSegue method.

```
// 3. Adopt and implement the delegate protocol
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, CitySelectionDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var selectRegion: UIButton!

   func pickCity(with selectedCity: String) {
      self.selectRegion.text = selectedCity
   }

 /*please pay attention. In this case you must reference the   
 navigation controller first and the your can get the right 
 instance of the delegate variable inside your firstVC (I called   
 firstVC but in your case is Select Region Page*/

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
         // you MUST set the right identifier 
        if segue.identifier == "showFirst" {
            if let navController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
                if let firstVC = navController.topViewController as? FirstViewController{
                    firstVC.delegate = self
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

since you have another VC (embedded in a navigation controller), also this one must conform to the delegate like so:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CitySelectionDelegate {

var delegate: CitySelectionDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func pickCity(with selectedCity: String){
    // here you simply call the delegate method again and you dismiss the navigation controller 
    self.delegate?.pickCity(with: selectedCity)
    self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showSecond" {
        if let controller = segue.destination as? SelectCityPage {
            controller.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use delegate or block or notification when secVC action to change the firstVC value you needed.
2. Or you set a property in secVC and pass the value in firstVC you want to change, So you can change value passed from firstVC in secVC.